# linear combinations of of irrational number with integer coefficients.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\{x_1, \dots,x_k\}$ be real numbers, under which conditions do I have that the set 
$$
\langle x_1, \dots,x_k\rangle
=
\{\sum a_i x_i: a_i \in \mathbb{Z} \}
$$
is discrete set?

Well, this is clearly the case if $x_i$'s are all integers. On the other hand, if I take $x_1=1$ and $x_2$ to be the [Liouville Constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number), I have a dense set. So what would be necessary and/or sufficient conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\frac x y$ is irrational then $\{nx+my:n,m \in \mathbb Z\}$ is dense. If $\frac x y$ is rational then $\{nx+my:n,m \in \mathbb Z\}$  is discrete.